# Office Authentication from a button in an Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, office-scripts

I would like to have a button in a worksheet that:

1. reads some data from the worksheet,
2. makes a call to a remote endpoint using Office Authentication,
3. writes the response back in the worksheet.

There are several potential ways to do this: Office Scripts, Office Add-ins (with the new JS API), VBA, and old-style add-ins (COM or Excel Add-ins).
All of them however present difficulties that I couldn't solve.

**Office Scripts**

Neither `OfficeRuntime.auth` nor `Office.auth` are available from Office Scripts. Moreover, the `fetch` API is only available for scripts saved on a user's OneDrive folder, not for scripts saved in Sharepoint.

**Office Add-ins**

I could almost make it work, but only as a task panel add-in.

The code would be something like the following:

```
async function button_click() {
    await Excel.run( async (context) => {

        let my_sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('my_sheet');
        let my_data = my_sheet.getRange('my_data');
        let request_data = do_stuff(my_data);
        
        let token = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken();
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Authorization', token);
        let response = await fetch(SERVICE_URL,{
            headers: headers,
            body: request_data
        })

        let my_output = my_sheet.getRange('my_output');
        my_output.values = response.body;
        
    })
}
```

The problem here is: how can I trigger the function from a button *in the worksheet*? I have several different buttons and I prefer to keep the UI in the worksheet.

**VBA**

VBA has the opposite problem: it is easy to trigger actions from the worksheet, but there is no library (that I know of) implementing Office Authentication. Even the excellent [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) only implements OAuth2 with client credentials (username and password).

**COM and Excel Add-ins**

Honestly, I haven't tried. Add-ins deployment and updating are cumbersome and have caused me many headaches in the past. I would rather use one of the other methods if possible.

**My question: How can I call a remote service using Office Authentication from a button in a worksheet?**

More in detail:

Is there a way in Office Scripts to access `Office.auth`?

How can I invoke a function in an Office Add-in from a button in a worksheet?

Is there something equivalent to `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken`in VBA?

Comment: I suggest to add the office-js tag to your post, to attract people who are more familiar with office-js programming.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in Office Scripts to access Office.auth?

No. Office Scripts does not have access to any of the Office JS APIs. You can only use the [ExcelScript API surface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript?view=office-scripts).

> How can I invoke a function in an Office Add-in from a button in a worksheet?

You could make a [content add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins). However, this would not be the same as a [Script button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/script-buttons?view=office-scripts) that uses Excel shapes as buttons.